# Prisma JSON upsert "must not be null"

Tags: json, prisma, prisma2

I have the following schema:

```
myField              Json?                          @default("{}")
```

(notice the ?)

And when I try to insert a null value to that json field I get:

> ... must not be null. Please use undefined instead

I then tried to make it work with `Prisma.JsonNull`:

```
await prisma.website.upsert({
    update: {myField: data.myField || Prisma.JsonNull...},
    create:  {myField: data.myField || Prisma.JsonNull...},
  });
```

But then I got:

> ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first I had to insert `Prisma.JsonNull` instead of a javascript `null`.
Then I figured out that the problem stemmed from Nextjs that couldn't serialize the `Prisma.JsonNull` so I just did the following trick in my `getStaticProps`:
`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mydata with Prisma.JsonNull))`